# How to move an object with keys

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I don't understand why this won't work, can anyone help me, I'm using p5.js and it won't work:

```js
let x = 50, y = 50;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(200, 200);
}

function draw() {
  rect(x, y, 50, 50);
  if (this.keyPressed(87)) {
    y -= 5;
  } else if (keyIsDown(83)) {
    y += 5;
  } else if (keyIsDown(65)) {
    x -= 5;
  } else if (keyIsDown(68)) {
    x += 5;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide more code, please? It's hard to say what's going wrong based on this snippet. At a guess, `x += 5` etc should probably be something like `this.x += 5`, as right there, you're just referencing a local variable

Comment: No idea why it "won't work" - we don't even know what it's supposed to do when it does work.

Comment: It makes an object move with arrow keys @James

Comment: @dolphin30 we understand that, but we don't have any context as to when this function is being called, how x/y are being used outside of this code snippet, or basically anything else. We need more info to help

Comment: Without seeing more if your code it's hard to say what might be wrong, but calling `this.keyPressed(87)` in your first if statement doesn't make a lot of sense. Did you mean `keyIsDown(87)`?

You should consider using a code snippet which lets you embed runnable HTML/javascript in your StackOverflow question. And remember it is best if your question has a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I updated your question to use a snippet and filled in some missing parts by inference, and sure enough it results in an error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.keyPressed is not a function`

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: You need to provide what error message is being seen and like others have said, the community can help if you provide more info such as what keyIsDown() is doing.

Also, could it be that rect(x, y, 50, 50); is supposed to occur after your If statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling `keyIsDown(87)` instead of `this.keyPressed(87)` in the first if statement. With this change the A-W-S-D keys can be used to move the rectangle (note, click the sketch to make sure it has focus before using they keyboard).

```js
let x = 50, y = 50;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(200, 200);
}

function draw() {
  rect(x, y, 50, 50);
  // This used to be this.keyPressed(87) which caused an error
  if (keyIsDown(87)) {
    y -= 5;
  } else if (keyIsDown(83)) {
    y += 5;
  } else if (keyIsDown(65)) {
    x -= 5;
  } else if (keyIsDown(68)) {
    x += 5;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```